# With .NET regular expressions, is it possible to capture Groups within repeated Captures?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm validating a string that must consist of a prefix that matches a pattern (call it `pat1`), followed by 0 or more repeating patterns, each containing 3 sub-patterns (`pat2`, `pat3`, `pat4`) that I'd like to capture individually. Simplified a bit, the regex basically looks like this:

```
^pat1 ((pat2) (pat3) (pat4))*$
```

The `^` and `$` anchors are present because the match should fail if the string contains any extraneous characters at the beginning or end.

Using `Regex.Match` against a valid expression, I get a `Match` object with the following characteristics:

- 5 `Groups`, consisting of the entire expression, the *last* matched group (i.e. last occurrence of `pat2 pat3 pat4`), and matches for the last `pat2`, `pat3`, and `pat4` individually. That's all well documented and exactly as expected.
- `Groups[1].Captures` containing a `Capture` for *each* occurrence of `pat2 pat3 pat4`. Also as expected.

What I can't figure out how to do is extract `pat2`, `pat3`, and `pat4` *indidually* from *each* `Capture`. **Is this even possible with a single execution of a single Regex?** I'm starting to think not. (If `Capture` had a `Groups` property, that's probably exactly what I'd need. But it doesn't.)

If I take a completely different approach using `Regex.Matches` instead of `Regex.Match`, I think I could capture all the individual bits I need, but it wouldn't validate that the string cannot contain extraneous characters before, after, or between the matches.

So what I've resorted to for now is executing the original expression, iterating through `Groups[1].Captures` and executing a Regex again (this time just `(pat2) (pat3) (pat4)`) just to parse out the 3 groups within each capture. This feels like I'm making the engine repeat work that's already been done, but maybe it's the only way?

As a side-note, I did a lot of searching for "groups within captures", etc., and was very surprised to come up empty. I would think this is a common scenario, which makes me wonder if I should be taking a completely different approach. I'm open to any suggestion that meets all validation and capturing requirements in a reasonably efficient manner.

Comment: Name the capture groups, then it's easy to extract them.

Comment: Can you produce a working example of the code?

Comment: Say, [this is your regex and a string](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5epat1%28+%28pat%5cd%29+%28pat%5cd%29+%28pat%5cd%29%29*%24&i=pat1+pat2+pat3+pat4+pat5+pat6+pat7). What output do you need *exactly*?

Comment: Do you realize `pat2`, `pat3`, and `pat4` are in Group 2, Group 3 and Group 4? They are not in Group 1. You can't find any info about groups inside captures because it is vice versa.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In addition to confirming that the string matches the expression as a whole, I would want to capture `pat2`, `pat3`, `pat4`, `pat5`, `pat6`, and `pat7` as 6 individual strings. Thanks!

Comment: So, you already do it. Study the linked post, it is all explained there.

Comment: Wow...I wonder if I missed something obvious here...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't know if I'd call it "obvious" but I did miss it. The first set of 3 captured values I want are at `Groups[2].Captures[0]`, `Groups[3].Captures[0]`, `Groups[4].Captures[0]`, next are at `Groups[2].Captures[1]`, `Groups[3].Captures[1]`, `Groups[4].Captures[1]`, and so on. Intuitively the nesting seems backwards, but it is indeed all there. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why "backwards"? It is vice versa, numbered capturing groups are numbered from left to right. Are a native speaker of an RTL writing language?

Comment: By "backwards" I don't mean RTL, I mean the Groups/Captures hierarchy feels inverted in this case. Ignoring the domain of regexes for a moment, we basically have a "collection of collections". I would expect to find my first group of 3 things at `outer[0].inner[0, 1, 2]`. Instead, they are at `outer[0, 1, 2].inner[0]`. Not suggesting it's wrong, just explaining why at a glance it feels unintuitive. Hope that makes sense.